# com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream

Tags: android, protocols, protocol-buffers, grpc-java, protobuf-java

I am getting

> "Program type already present:
>   com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream"
>   runtime error.I have tried using multidix and also referred more links
>   but still didnt get any solutions.

This is because in protobuf lite and protobuf jar file as the same class .My dependency is,

```
    protobuf {
        protoc {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.6.1'
        }
        plugins {
            grpc {
                artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.0-pre2'
            }
            javalite {
                artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
            }
        }
        generateProtoTasks {
            all()*.plugins {
                javalite {}
            }
            ofNonTest()*.plugins {
                grpc {
                    // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        //  GRPC dependencies
        implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
        implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.14.0'
        implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.14.0'
        implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.14.0'
        implementation files('libs/protobuf-java-3.6.1.jar')

    }
```

Since my library file and protobuf plugin the both below

```
artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
 implementation files('libs/protobuf-java-3.6.1.jar')
```

is generating same java class in there jar file due to this i may getting this error "Program type already present"

I have tried multidex,exclude code but its all not working

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.grpc.helloworldexample"
        // API level 14+ is required for TLS since Google Play Services v10.2
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug { minifyEnabled false }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'GoogleAppIndexingWarning', 'HardcodedText', 'InvalidPackage'
        textReport true
        textOutput "stdout"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude '**/AbstractMessageLite.java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using multidix and also referred more links but still didnt get any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and it was caused by using different version of protobuf library in one of my project dependency.

Run command `gradle dependencies` to see all dependencies.

I solved the issue by removing my protobuf dependency and keep one version only.